# warning: render(...) React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
index.js:1 Warning: render(...): Replacing React-rendered children with a new root component. If you intended to update the children of this node, you should instead have the existing children update their state and render the new components instead of calling ReactDOM.render.


changeCategory = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const filteredCars = this.state.cars
            .filter((car) => e.target.id === car.category)
            .map((car, index) => {
                return (
                    <Car
                        key={index}
                        title={car.title}
                        category={car.category}
                        image={car.image}
                        money={car.money}
                        checkCar={this.checkCarModalHandler}
                        data-category={car.category}
                    />
                );
            });
        ReactDOM.render(filteredCars, document.querySelector('.card-cars'));
    }, 500);
};
```

Но на работу эта ошибка не влияет как я вижу

```
<div className='autopark-categorys'>
    <ul>
        {this.state.category.map((category, index) => {
            return (
                <Category
                    key={index}
                    category={category}
                    onChangeCategory={this.changeCategory}
                />
            );
        })}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: нужен код, который выдает такую ошибку

Comment: я добавил код. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку с нужной категорией у меня появляется эта ошибка

Comment: а зачем тебе делать это внутри setTimeout?

Comment: Я хочу потом сделать лоадер и setTimeout на это не влияет я уже пробовал

Comment: да, не тот вопрос :) зачем ты это делаешь через `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: А я незнаю как ещё зарендерить в html эту функцию

Comment: а как ты используешь changeCategory?

Comment: при клике на кнопку с названием категории

Comment: Я добавил код где я использую

Comment: По коду непонятно какое поведение ожидается. Попробуй сделать минимальный пример со всеми компонентами, чтобы было видно что куда вставляется. Пока видно, что ты вместо того, чтобы просто обновить state вручную работаешь с компонентами, но непонятно, на сколько осознанно

Comment: Когда я нажимаю на кнопку с нужной категорией у меня должно из всех машин выбраться те машины которые находяться в той категории на которую я нажал

Comment: Все правильно, ты их выбираешь и кладешь в state - и в нужном месте у тебя автоматом все выводится

Comment: Извините но я слишком туплю сейчас. Как исправить эту ошибку можете скинуть ссылку пожалуйста что сделать надо я просто не мог найти не где

Comment: _Как исправить эту ошибку_ - переписать метод `changeCategory` чтобы в нем просто устанавливался `state`